# Finiteness of the spectrum of the ring of idempotents of an artinian ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an artinian commutative ring.
Let $\mathrm{Idem}(A)$ be the ring of idempotents of $A$ for
$$ e \boxplus e' = ee' \text{ and } e \boxtimes e' = (e - e')^2. $$
I would like to prove that $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathrm{Idem}(A))$ is finite.

For the sake of contradiction, assume that there is an infinite sequence $\mathfrak{b}_1, \mathfrak{b}_2, \ldots$
of distinct elements of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathrm{Idem}(A))$.
Using the fact that the ideals $\mathfrak{b}_i$ are maximal, we can prove that the ideals $\mathfrak{b}_i A$ and $\mathfrak{b}_j A$ are coprime for $i \not= j$.
So, by the chinese remainder theorem, forall $n \ge 1$, we have a surjective morphism
$$ f_n : A \longrightarrow A/\mathfrak{b}_1 A \times \cdots \times A/\mathfrak{b}_n A. $$
The sequence $(\ker f_n)_{n \ge 1}$ is decreasing. How can I prove that it is strictly decreasing ?

Comment: It looks like you are assuming commutativity. Could you please add that to your post and/or add the [commutative-algebra] tag?

Comment: Why should prime ideals in $\operatorname{Idem}(A)$ be maximal?

Comment: @egreg because an integral boolean algebra is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: More directly, every Boolean ring is zero dimensional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would prefer to write $e\boxplus e'=e+e-2ee'$ since this is actually the addition operation in that ring.

Note that if $e$ and $e'$ are orthogonal idempotents, then $e+e'=e\boxplus e'$. When $A$ is Artinian, it has a complete set of primtive orthogonal idempotents [in the sense of a semiperfect ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_ring#Semiperfect_ring).  Notice then that this complete set of idempotents $B$ remains a complete set of idempotents in the boolean ring of idempotents. Moreover, they remain primitive, because $eBe\subseteq eAe$, and $eAe$ only has two idempotents, so $eBe$ only has two idempotents.

This means that $B$, in addition to being a boolean ring, is also a semiperfect ring, but a semiperfect boolean ring is semisimple (a finite product of fields.)

If we can decompose $B$ into $n$ fields, then it has precisely $n$ prime ideals (all the prime ideals being maximal.) We have shown then that the $Spec(B)$ is finite.

Comment: I think a good generalization of your problem is that to replace “ Artinian” with “orthogonally finite”.